# How can i fix this mvn terminal execution error?

Tags: java, maven

While i try to execute mvn, i am getting this error:

```
> mvn -version
---------------------------------------------------
...
...
constituent[38]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3/libexec/lib/maven-core-3.6.3.jar
constituent[39]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3/libexec/lib/javax.inject-1.jar
constituent[40]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3/libexec/lib/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
constituent[41]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3/libexec/lib/guava-25.1-android.jar
constituent[42]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3/libexec/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.cli.Option.builder(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/commons/cli/Option$Builder;
    at org.apache.maven.cli.CLIManager.<init>(CLIManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.cli(MavenCli.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:278)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

After that, i did `brew info maven` and got this:

```
maven: stable 3.6.3
Java-based project management
https://maven.apache.org/
Conflicts with:
  mvnvm (because also installs a 'mvn' executable)
/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3 (87 files, 10.7MB) *
  Built from source on 2019-12-14 at 21:17:10
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/maven.rb
==> Requirements
Required: java >= 1.7 ✔
==> Analytics
install: 62,288 (30 days), 155,438 (90 days), 543,248 (365 days)
install-on-request: 58,104 (30 days), 146,680 (90 days), 512,969 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

Do you know if the error is related to the conflict with mvnvm or how fix it?
It happens the same while running every mvn command.
BTW, I'm running it in macOS 10.15.2 with Java 1.8.

Comment: can you try `mvn --version` furthermore can you check if `M2_HOME` exists in your environment ..?

Comment: the same is happening with ```mvn --version```, and ```M2_HOME``` exist and is currently pointing to the maven home path